# Problems when client connects(godot c#)

Tags: c#, godot, multiplayer, godot4

So, I try to experiment with godot(4.1) multiplayer and I am stuck for quite some time. The problem is that the server is connecting as expected, but when a client connects the player doesn't spawn (i have set the multiplayer spawner correctly) and the server crashes. I am running 2 instances on the same machine and I am using the loopback ip to connect. I also use Linux(Arch)

```
using Godot;
using System;

namespace Multiplayer
{
    public partial class Multiplayer : Node
    {
        const int MAXPLAYER = 2;
        const int PORT = 5555; 
        [Export]
        private PackedScene _levelScene;
        private Control _ui;


        public override void _Ready() => _ui = GetNode<Control>("UI");

        private void OnHostButtonPressed()
        {
            //Start as server
            var peer = new ENetMultiplayerPeer();
            peer.CreateServer(PORT, MAXPLAYER);
            //Check if connection was succesfull
            if(peer.GetConnectionStatus() == MultiplayerPeer.ConnectionStatus.Disconnected){
                GD.Print("Failde to start server");
                return;
            }
            GD.Print("Server establised");
            //Set multiplayer peer 
            Multiplayer.MultiplayerPeer = peer;
            //Start game
            StartGame();
        }

        private void OnConnectButtonPressed()
        {
            var peer = new ENetMultiplayerPeer();
            //Get ip and check for empty
            var ip = RetrieveAddress();
            if(ip == String.Empty){
                    GD.Print("Ip can't be empty");
                    return;
            }
            //Create client
            peer.CreateClient(ip,PORT);
            //Check connection
            if(peer.GetConnectionStatus() == MultiplayerPeer.ConnectionStatus.Disconnected){
                GD.Print("Failed to start multiplayer client.");
                return;
            }
            GD.Print("Client connected");
            //Set client
            Multiplayer.MultiplayerPeer = peer;
            StartGame();
        }

        private void StartGame(){
            //Disable hud
            if(!Multiplayer.IsServer())
                _ui.Hide(); 
        }

        private void OnStartButtonPressed()
        {
            //If server change scene
            if(Multiplayer.IsServer()){
                CallDeferred(nameof(ChangeLevel), _levelScene);
                _ui.Hide(); 
            }
        }

        private void ChangeLevel(PackedScene scene){
            var level = GetNode<Node>("Level");
            //Remove old level
            foreach (var child in level.GetChildren()){
                level.RemoveChild(child);
                child.QueueFree();
            }
            //Load new level
            level.AddChild(scene.Instantiate());
        }   

        private string RetrieveAddress(){
            return GetNode<LineEdit>("UI/VBoxContainer/HBoxContainer/Remote").Text;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Godot;

namespace Multiplayer
{
    public partial class PlayerInput : MultiplayerSynchronizer
    {
        public bool isJumping = false;
        [Export]
        Vector2 motion;

        // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
        public override void _Ready()
        {
            //Give input control to local player
            SetProcess(GetMultiplayerAuthority() == Multiplayer.GetUniqueId());
        }

        public void Jump(){
            GD.Print("Jump again");
            isJumping = true;
        }

        // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
        public override void _Process(double delta)
        {
            //Movement
            if(Input.IsActionJustPressed("Jump")){
                GD.Print("Jump");
                //Rpc(nameof(Jump));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class level : Node2D
{
    [Export]
    private PackedScene playerScene;
    private int id;
    private Node2D spawnPoint;

    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {   
        //Get spawn point
        spawnPoint = GetNode<Node2D>("Player");

        //Get id
        id = Multiplayer.GetUniqueId();

        //We only need to spawn players on the server
        if(!Multiplayer.IsServer())
            return;

        //Connect signals
        Multiplayer.PeerConnected += ctx => AddPlayer(id);
        Multiplayer.PeerDisconnected += RemovePlayer;

        //Spawn player
        foreach(var peer in Multiplayer.GetPeers()){
            AddPlayer(peer);
        }

        //Spawn server
        AddPlayer(1);
    }

    private void AddPlayer(int id){
        GD.Print("Adding player ");
        //Initialize player
        var player = (Player)playerScene.Instantiate();
        player.Name = id.ToString();
        //Add to scene
        spawnPoint.AddChild(player, true);
        //Set player id
        player.playerId = (int)id;
    }

    private void RemovePlayer(long id){
        GD.Print("Despawn player " + id.ToString());    
        spawnPoint.GetNode<CharacterBody2D>(id.ToString()).QueueFree();
    }

    // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
    }
}
```

```
using Godot;
using Multiplayer;

public partial class Player : CharacterBody2D
{
    private float Gravity = ProjectSettings.GetSetting("physics/2d/default_gravity").AsSingle();
    [Export]
    private int spd = 200;
    [Export]
    private int jumpForce = 500;
    [Export]
    private float gravityScale = 1.0f;
    private PlayerInput _input;
    public int playerId{
        get{return playerId;}
        set{
            GD.Print("PlayerId: " + value);
            _input = GetNode<PlayerInput>("InputSynchronizer");
            _input.SetMultiplayerAuthority(value);
        }
    }


    public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta){
        Movement(delta);
        //Apply movement
        MoveAndSlide();
    }

    private void Movement(double delta)
    {
        var motion = Velocity;

        //Gravity
        motion.Y += Gravity * (float)delta * gravityScale;

        //Jump
        if(_input.isJumping && IsOnFloor()){
            motion.Y = -jumpForce; 
            _input.isJumping = false;
        }

        //Horizonta movement
        var dir = Input.GetAxis("Left", "Right");
        motion.X = dir * spd;
        //Apply to velocity
        Velocity = motion;
    }
}
```

I tried to find where the problem produces exactly but the game crashes and the last message is "client connected

Comment: I usually in cases like this create a log file and write debug data to the log.